# Can't refresh token, different origin

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I have a web app that connects to my server side app.The web app gets the auth code while the server stores the tokens and refreshes the access tokens. When I issue api calls from localhost(both the web and server side parts are on the same domain) when my access tokens expire, I can normally refresh the tokens. When I deploy my code so that the web part is on domain A and the server api on domain B, refreshing the access tokens after expiration don't work. I guess it's an origin issue. I got web app keys from google console.
Does anyone know if there is a setting to enable cross origin for oauth?

Update: Maybe it doesn't have to do with cors. The problem is that I can run my app from localhost and not from my cloud deployed app.

Comment: when you deploy does `http` schema by any chance changes to `https` ?

Comment: Yes it does. Is this affecting my app?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using ASP.NET WebApi 2.0? If so please refer to this article:

http://blog.rfaisal.com/2014/01/14/building-your-own-api-and-securing-it-with-oauth-2-0-in-asp-net-webapi-2/

Basically you need to:

1. Install this nuget package: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
2. In your WebApiConfig.Register method use the extension method EnableCors() on your HttpConfiguration object:

   ```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
      config.EnableCors();
   }
   ```
3. Decorate your controllers with this attribute:

   ```
   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
   ```

I hope this is useful!

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I think it's google who should have cors. I wanted to know if there was a flag i could set in my requests(maybe i wasn't clear about it).

Answer (score 1):

There might be same-domain policy that is ruining your day because the schema is different.

Two pages are considered to be from the same origin if they have the same host, protocol and port.

[From Wikipedia on the same origin policy:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

> The term "origin" is defined using the domain name, application layer
>   protocol, and (in most browsers) TCP port of the HTML document running
>   the script. Two resources are considered to be of the same origin if
>   and only if all these values are exactly the same.

Comment: It does ruin my day, and the last few days as well :) . Thanks for the info. I have to dig deeper in google oauth spec.